# Unable to get the desired result set in SQL

Tags: sql

**Problem Statement:**

In Sql I'm trying to get the result set mentioned in the image 2 using pivot query,but i'm not getting the desired result.It would be great if any one gives the suggestions.

**Image1: (Current Result Set)**

[image]

**Image2: Desired Output**

[image]

Comment: I removed the extraneous database tags.  Feel free to add the *one* database you are actually using.  You should also show whatever query you have tried.

Comment: Another "read my mind" question ? Why is the desired output desired ? What have you tried ? What did not work ?

Comment: And what's the input?

Comment: What if different col2 values for one col1 value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `group by` col1.

```
select col1, max(col2), max(col3), max(col4), max(col5)
from tablename --or query that produces the current resultset
group by col1
```